# How to use money js in angular 4

Tags: angular

I've been trying to implement moneyjs in angular4 app

and i wanted to use in component like this

```
import * as fx from 'money/money.js';
```

the thing i am confused is where to configure the exchange rates

```
 fx.rates = {
        GBP: 0.6,
        USD: 1
    };
 fx.base = USD;
```

i could have done this in construction of my component, but i don't want to repeat the configuration in individual component, so this should be configured in main module that is **app.module.ts** in my case i am using **angular-cli**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better create a `service` like `money.service.ts` and do all your configuration inside that service `constructor`. Then inject that service whenever you need.

Comment: Thank you, now i got it. Let me try